# Laravel Eloquent ORM Where Statements for Date Timestamp comparison on default created_at timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, date, laravel, where-clause

So i have this code wish is supposed to retrieve me some view for a web service.

```
 $records = Publication::all();

            if(isset($headers["input"]["from"])) {
                $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $headers["input"]["from"])->toDateTimeString();
                $records = $records->where("created_at", ">", $from);
            }

            if(isset($headers["input"]["until"])) {
                $until = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $headers["input"]["until"])->toDateTimeString();
                $records = $records->where("created_at", "<", $until);
            }
```

This should return me some publications when passing a GET argument of 2015-07-21 already... But it returns nothing. I tried testing to see what was going on doing a dd($results) after the code but i got nothing on any way i have tried. I tried passing ->get() and ->all() and still got nothing. I even tried calling only the method and not assign to the same $record variable although it did not make sense to me i was all in about fixing this.

Maybe is a problem with Sql Statement? Comparing dates? Carbon variables look fine when dd($until) or dd($from)

EDIT: Since i needed this to work i explored other ways... What i did was transform Publication::all() to Publication::query() ( this will get you QueryBuilder ) Then i worked with Query Builder ->where(field,comparison,value) and then finally retrieved the result with $records->get(); That Way you will still get the Model Collection because if you use DB::table('publications') and then the same code when you do ->get() you will only get the array of elements and no relationship loading like in model. Hope i made my point and explained well. And sorry if i did not. I really tried my best. This is now SOLVED!

Comment: This is **SOLVED...**

Comment: Please put solutions to your own questions in an answer, not the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i needed this to work i explored other ways... What i did was transform Publication::all() to Publication::query() ( this will get you QueryBuilder ) Then i worked with Query Builder ->where(field,comparison,value) and then finally retrieved the result with $records->get(); That Way you will still get the Model Collection because if you use DB::table('publications') and then the same code when you do ->get() you will only get the array of elements and no relationship loading like in model. Hope i made my point and explained well. And sorry if i did not. I really tried my best. This is now SOLVED!